# can we mock a private class in Mokito?

Tags: java, junit

what I need to do is to mock method inside of my private class.
Any tips on how to do it?

```
   public class myPublicClass {

    //
    private static class myPrivateCalss {

         public static method1() {
               //do some stuff
         }
    }

  }
```

Comment: A `private class` is an *implementation detail* you should not mock it since your test should not even know it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You must to use PowerMock to mock this private class.

Comment: I donwote becouse you gave the OP a loaded gun without advice how to use it.

Comment: Ok. No problem!  Here are a example how to do it.

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyPublicClass.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldMockPrivateInnerClass() {
                MyPublicClass.MyPrivateClass innerClassMock = mock(MyPublicClass.MyPrivateClass.class);
               whenNew(MyPublicClass.MyPrivateClass.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(innerClassMock);
         MyPublicClass myClass = new MyPublicClass();
         assertNotNull(myClass);

    }
}

Comment: @Mychell Teixeria it does not work as eclipse asks me to change the visibility of my inner class to public

Comment: @MychellTeixeira: Thats not what I meant: PowerMock enables the OP to brake basic unittesting rules such as "verify behavior, not code". You should [change](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55835409/edit) your answer to explain that.